# ng-class not behaving properly

Tags: angularjs

i have below lines of code with ng-repeat and ng-class:

```
<div ng-repeat="invitee in invitedCollaborators" class="invite-collabs-emails">
     <input type="text" id="email-{{$index}}" validate-email="email.invalid" ng-class="{'collabs-email-required' : ((invitedCollaborators[{{$index}}].email == null || invitedCollaborators[{{$index}}].email ==''))}" class="collabs-email" placeholder="Enter email here" ng-required="true" ng-model="invitee.email"/>
     <a href ng-click="removeInvitee($index)" class="delete-invite">
       <img src="delete-invite.png">
     </a>
    </div>
<a href class="add-another-collabs-link" ng-click="addAnotherCollaborator()">Add another</a>
```

ng-repeat is repeating the input box when we are adding another. ng-class has this conditional statement to add collabs-email-required class which adds red border color to show that input is required.

Now problem im facing is that when i add more than one input box and enter valid email in all of them and then remove one of the input box, the other input boxes show me red border color, even though they have valid email ids.

I tried adding the ternary operator in ng-class to make it work:

```
ng-class="{'collabs-email-required' : ((invitedCollaborators[{{$index}}].email == null || invitedCollaborators[{{$index}}].email =='')) ? 'collabs-email'}
```

Here above problem gets resolved but then the input box doesnt show red colored border when it gets out of focus. It should have the red border when its out of focus and not filled with valid id (or not filled at all).

What condition am i missing? Please help. Thanks

Comment: `ng-` part makes it angular already, you don't need `{{ ... }}` for your variables, so use `$index` without brackets

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, hey man thanks for the quick reply, i removed the angular expression around $index and tried, and it works perfectly.. Such a goofy mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  <div ng-repeat="invitee in invitedCollaborators" class="invite-collabs-emails">
         <input type="text" id="email-{{$index}}" validate-email="email.invalid" ng-class="{'collabs-email-required' : ((invitedCollaborators[$index].email == null || invitedCollaborators[$index].email ==''))}" class="collabs-email" placeholder="Enter email here" ng-required="true" ng-model="invitee.email"/>
         <a href ng-click="removeInvitee($index)" class="delete-invite">
           <img src="delete-invite.png">
         </a>
        </div>
    <a href class="add-another-collabs-link" ng-click="addAnotherCollaborator()">Add another</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Aref. As suggested by Alexey, i had removed the expression around $index and it worked